# Why does VS-Code not Recognize "__dirname"?

Tags: typescript, backend, nestjs

Im currently working on a backend project where I need to read out data from a JSon File but VS Code does not recognize the variable "__dirname".

I have tried different things in case of changing my code but none worked.

```
private ourPathToFile = `${__dirname} ~/Desktop/richwood/dhbw-richie-backend/dhbw-third-semester-training-data/training-data.json`
```

Cannot find name '__dirname'

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the node types?

```
npm i @types/node --save-dev
yarn add -D @types/node
```

The [node types define the global `__dirname`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/acb3cb292ba5dcebfbe70f260c1beb55588f0750/types/node/globals.d.ts#L171).